# Have to square each number in the array and then sum the results together. What do I do wrong?

Tags: c#

```cs
public static int SquareSum(int[] numbers)
{ 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
        sum += Math.Sqrt(numbers[i]);
    }
        
    return sum;
}
```

I get a message

> The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You say that you want to square each number but that code is attempting to get the square root of each number, so the complete opposite.

Comment: Which editor are you using? I think most IDEs should help you solve that problem easily.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
using System;
```

At the beginning of your class.

Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-6.0

Comment: Oh, ok. So since this is a kata they want me not to use methods? Or maybe they just forgot to write it in the class in the first place?

Comment: @George You are using Math.Sqrt which gives the square root of a number which is the opposite of what your question says!

Comment: If you don't use Visual Studio or IDE that helps with that, then you need to take care adding stuff like using system manually. Best way is to check Microsoft documention to clarify what is required

Comment: If this is a kata & you are not supposed to use methods then don't - squaring a number does not require a method you just multiply it by itself. sum += (numbers[i] * numbers[i]); - Your error message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

use `using System;` :

```
using System;
```

or press Ctrl+. when you are on Math then hit Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Since Math is the part of "System" namespace, you can either add the following line in your file:

```
using System;
```

OR rewrite the line as:

```
//sum += Math.Sqrt(numbers[i]);
sum += System.Math.Sqrt(numbers[i]);
```

Further, as the Math.Sqrt() return type is double, you need to change SquareSum() and the variable sum types to double or use casting alternatively.

Comment: That will fix the error message but will give a wrong answer. You should take care to read the question carefully.

Comment: Oops... Square Root vs Square...